# Find sufficient and necessary condition for $f(|x|,y^2)$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y):\mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}$ be differentiable at $(0,0)$.
Let $h(x,y)=f(|x|,y^2)$.
Find sufficient and necessary condition for $h(x,y)$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$. I suspect it has to be something about the chain rule, but $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$. Could some give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Observe what has to happen for:
$$D_1 h(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{f(|t|,0)-f(0,0)}{t}$$
to exist $(D_1 f(0,0)=0)$.

Then look that if that actually happens, then $D_1 h(0,0)=0$. Calculate $D_2 h(0,0)$ with the chain rule (possible because $g(t):=h(0,t)=f(0,t^2)$ is derivable).
Then, using what you've got, and the inequalities $||(|x|,y)||\geq ||(|x|,y^2)||$, $y\in(-1,1)$ and $||(|x|,y)||\geq |y|$ bound:
$$0\leq\left|\dfrac{h(x,y)-h(0,0)-D_1 h(0,0)\cdot x-D_2 h(0,0)\cdot y}{||(x,y)||}\right|=\\=\left|\dfrac{f(|x|,y^2)-f(0,0)}{||(|x|,y)||}\right|=\left|\dfrac{f(|x|,y^2)-f(0,0)-D_y f(0,0)\cdot y^2}{||(|x|,y)||}+\dfrac{D_y f(0,0)\cdot y^2}{||(|x|,y)||}\right|\leq\\ \leq\left|\dfrac{f(|x|,y^2)-f(0,0)-D_y f(0,0)\cdot y^2}{||(|x|,y)||}\right|+\left|\dfrac{D_y f(0,0)\cdot y^2}{||(|x|,y)||}\right|\leq\\ \leq\left|\dfrac{f(|x|,y^2)-f(0,0)-D_y f(0,0)\cdot y^2}{||(|x|,y^2)||}\right|+\left|\dfrac{D_y f(0,0)\cdot y^2}{|y|}\right|$$
And taking $(h,k)=(|x|,y^2)\to(0,0)$ first limit is $0$ by $f$ differentiability. The second one is obviously $0$. So by sandwitch $h$ is diff.

Comment: for the condition of $D_1 h(0,0)$ i suspect it is $f(x,0)$ is even function, then $f|t|=f(t)$ , but I cant see how it goes to $D_1 h(0,0)=0$ 
and the limit exist for $D_2 h(0,0)$ : $g(t)' =f(0,t^2)'=f(0,t^2)*2t$ 
then   $D_2 h(0,0)=0$
for the last expression did you concluded  that  $D_1 f(0,0)=D_2 f(0,0)=0$? then its limit goes to 0?(using f differentiability definition for f imposing $f(|x|,y^2)$?

Comment: f being even in its first variable is actually a good condition, its sufficient, but not necessary. The necessary and sufficient condition is that $D_1 f(0,0)=0$ (note that a function being even in its first variable always verifies $D_1 f(0,0)=0$). Then you can take limit on $D_1 h(0,0)$ with $t>0$ and $t<0$, and you will get 0 on both cases so $D_1 h(0,0)=0$.Then you substitute all this things getting the bound i gave you. Finally, if you rename $h=|x|,k=y^2$ and take limit when $(h,k)\to(0,0)$, you know by using $f$ differentiability that the limit is 0, so by sandwitch $h$ is diff.

Comment: To see that this condition is necessary just note that if h is diff. then $$D_1 h(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{f(|t|,0)-f(0,0)}{t}$$ and in order for this limit to exist, both lateral limits must coincide: $$\lim_{\substack{t\to 0\\ t>0}} \dfrac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{\substack{t\to 0 \\t<0}}\dfrac{f(-t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}$$ But note that the first one is $D_1 f(0,0)$ and the second one $-D_1 f(0,0)$, hence $D_1 f(0,0)=-D_1 f(0,0)$ and $D_1 f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: ok but the last expression misses $D_2f(0,0)y^2$  or somehow you concluded it is 0?

Comment: you're right, i edited first comment.